# Unix commandline to repeat command with pipes

Tags: command-line, unix, bash, pipe

I want to write a script that will repeat a commandline that usually contains pipes

```
./myscript.sh ls -lart |grep ^d
```

And in `myscript.sh` I do a bunch of stuff, and then want to execute `ls -lart |grep ^d` and pipe the output from that into something else.

(sorry in advance if this is really simple and has a 1-liner solution).

So far I have tried

```
$@ | someothercommand
```

and

```
$* | someothercommand
```

But to no avail...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way the shell parses the command line means that the inputs to your shell script will stop when it gets to the pipe. What you will probably have to do to get round this is put your command line in quotes, so:

```
./myscript.sh "ls -lart |grep ^d"
```

Then in your script use the `eval` command to execute it, as in:

```
 eval "$@" | someothercommand
```

Comment: Why not '`eval "$@"`' in the script?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler because bash will will stop processing arguments for the script when it gets to the pipe. bash will execute `./myscript ls -lart` and pipe whatever output it gets through `grep ^d`. I think the idea was to be able to use the output of `ls -lart | grep ^d` in the script.

Although `eval "$@"` would work just as well. The point is that the pipe character needs to be in quotes so that it is not parsed by the shell when the command is executed.

Comment: @Martin Hilton, thanks for the great answer - `eval` was what I was missing!

Comment: +1 @Martin Hilton for need to use quotes when pipes are involved

Comment: You got my up-vote anyway (y'day) for a not desperately well thought out question.  What I had in mind was: `myscript "ls -lart" "|grep ^d" "|sed 's/^/  /'"`, which has 3 arguments.  It isn't very sensible; but ignoring the extra arguments on the command line isn't all that sensible.  It's tricky.  If there is more than one argument to 'myscript', you really should do something with or about the extras.  But it is debatable whether the 3-argument command line I showed is really better than just erroring: `[ $# -gt 1 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 'command | pipeline'" 1>&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: I see what you meant now. It's a good point I'll edit the answer.